# Is there a way to return tuple of mixed variables in Jax helper function?

Tags: jax

On my path learning Jax, I tried to achieve something like

```
def f(x):
    return [x + 1, [1,2,3], "Hello"]

x = 1
new_x, a_list, str = jnp.where(
    x > 0,
    test(x),
    test(x + 1)
)
```

Well, Jax clearly does not support this. I tried searching online and went through quite a few docs, but I couldn't find a good answer.

Any help on how can I achieve this in Jax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, JAX functions like `jnp.where` only accept array arguments, not list or string arguments. Since you're using a function that is not compatible with JAX in the first place, it might be better to just avoid JAX conditionals and just use standard Python conditionals instead:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x):
    return [x + 1, [1,2,3], "Hello"]

x = 1

new_x, a_list, str_ = f(x) if x > 0 else f(x + 1)
```